# Switch from path bar to location bar permanently in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, gconf, preferences

As most of you know, you can switch between the visual location entry, and the text based one in Nautilus, by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

When I tried to set this value permanently in gconf-editor, it doesn't exist. When I tried to do it via the terminal, this is the message that I receive:

`No value to set for key: /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_location_entry`

I can still switch between the two via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but I'm stumped about the fix.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Answer edited out of the question*

To permanently switch from path bar to location bar, you can use [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools].

To install dconf-tools, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

After installing it, search for dconf-tools in the dash and open it.

From there, the setting is located at *org* -> *gnome* -> *nautilus* -> *preferences*.
You need to enable `always-use-location-entry` to always use the location toolbar instead of the path bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Truthfully, this is what helped me do what I wanted. The other answer that is user based is awesome, and on bigger systems, with multiple users, that is probably better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 26):

If you want to toggle between location bar or path bar without installing anything on your system open a terminal and type to enable the location bar

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry  true
```

[image]

and to disable it

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry  false
```

[image]

This setting is user based. You may need to restart Nautilus with `nautilus -q`.

---

The method is applicable for all current releases:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (*trusty*),
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*xenial*),
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (*bionic*),
- Ubuntu 18.10 (*cosmic*).

Comment: Still works with 18.10