# Execute file path

Tags: files

In Windows I have e.g. the following path: `R:\Documents\Common\User\textual.doc`. I copy this path and execute it through pasting it into »Run« or Windows Explorer. It automatically opens a document in Libreoffice.

Can anybody suggest a simple and (after some one-time typing) ONE-CLICK solution to do the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: Type in terminal: libreoffice /home/locationyourfileis/file.odt. It will automatically open the document in Libreoffice.

Comment: @Russo better yet, `xdg-open` instead of `libreoffice`, so that whichever handler is installed is automatically opened.

Comment: And essentially asked the same question earlier: https://askubuntu.com/questions/778154/windows-file-paths-in-ubuntu

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you just double click the file? What more do you need? Or just `libreoffice /path/to/file`?

Comment: @MarkKirby I would suggest to remove the mention of Windows paths from this question and the mention of "one-click opening" from the other question? That way it would match the answers better and we have no double-post.

Answer (score 4):

GNOME Shell already does this. GNOME Shell's run menu, opened using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, opens paths to files which are not executable using the appropriate handler application. I tested with a video file (`/usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase/Jenyfa Duncan - Australia.ogg`) and an ODT file (`~/foo.odt`).

With Unity, the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> run menu doesn't do this, but you can use `xdg-open` as noted elsewhere. To minimize typing, maybe create a command called `o` that links to `xdg-open`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xdg-open /usr/local/bin/o
```

Then: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, `o /path/to/some/file`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Gnome might do this, but on Unity it fails. There you can only open directories and executables, I think.

Comment: Yep. Unity's dash is pretty limited.

Comment: [Unity Dash](https://www.lifewire.com/complete-guide-ubuntu-unity-dash-2202066) works in this way.

Comment: @pa4080 is there anything particular in that you want to point to?

Comment: Within Unity `Alt`+`F2`  opens some 'raw' tool. But when we using `Super key` or `Super`+`F` it works.

Comment: @pa4080 no, it doesn't. It simply finds a matching file it has indexed and opens that. Try with any path that's not in the index.

Comment: Yes, you are right! In this case, do I need to remove my comments here?

Answer (score 3):

You can type in terminal:

```
libreoffice /home/locationyourfileis/file.odt
```

It will automatically open the document in Libreoffice.

Or even better as suggested by muru:

```
xdg-open /home/locationyourfileis/file.odt
```

Which will open the appropriate installed handler automatically.

Comment: You can also use ALT+F2 instead of opening a terminal if the OP wants something similar to the "Run" window of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a simple dialogue window that prompts you for a path to enter and then opens it with the appropriate application using `xdg-open` when you click "Ok".

This command uses `zenity` (normally preinstalled) for the dialogue window and `xsel` (you might have to install it using `sudo apt install xsel` first) to already insert your current clipboard content into the entry field as default value - that means you can even save the keystrokes to paste!

```
openpath="$(zenity --entry --title "Open file" --text "Enter a file path to open with the appropriate application:" --entry-text "$(xsel -b)")" && xdg-open "$openpath"
```

[image: zenity dialogue]

This command can be run from a terminal, but it is even more useful as a keyboard shortcut. You can go to **System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts** and assign it to a custom shortcut, like e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Note however that it must run in a Bash-compatible shell, sou you have to wrap it in `bash -c '...'` to use it as shortcut:

```
bash -c 'openpath="$(zenity --entry --title "Open file" --text "Enter a file path to open with the appropriate application:" --entry-text "$(xsel -b)")" && xdg-open "$openpath"'
```

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers provide different ways how to simulate »Windows Run« behaviour, I accidentally found a way how to simulate »Windows Explorer« behaviour.

**Within Nautilus**

- Open Nautilus and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This shortcut will switch Nautilus to show the Location bar instead of [Breadcrumbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)).
- Paste your path in the Location bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> two times. The first <kbd>Enter</kbd> will open the location directory and will highlight (select) the target file. The second one will open the file.
- *If you want to set the Location Bar in Nautilus as default check this answer: [Switch from path bar to location bar permanently in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101100/switch-from-path-bar-to-location-bar-permanently-in-nautilus).*

**Within Nemo**

- The approach and the shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) are exactly the same as above.
- *Nemo will remember your choice and you don't need to switch its default behaviour.*

**Demo**

[image]