# Where is the "Go" menu option in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I have a standard Ubuntu 20.04.3 desktop installation.

In some tutorials people are using a "go" menu option in order to access remote folders.

For example here:
https://frameboxxindore.com/linux/how-do-i-download-a-file-from-linux-server.html

they say "it’s under the menu bar “Go” > “Enter Location” >
Source: [https://frameboxxindore.com/linux/how-do-i-download-a-file-from-linux-server.html"](https://frameboxxindore.com/linux/how-do-i-download-a-file-from-linux-server.html%22)

I have been searching everywhere in the user interface, but I just can't seem to find where this "go" option is? Has it been removed and is there any way to use this "enter location" feature currently?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS regular desktop

Comment: Dear goodness, how can Linux make even file version numbers this complicated?

Comment: @N0rbert Well it discusses related matters, but it doesn't really explain what has happened. Has this "Go" -feature simply been removed from recent Ubuntu versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Go" menu does not anymore exist. Instead, you can hit the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This shows the location entry bar, where you can type (or paste) the URI of your remote folder. The same shortcut key is applicable in the GTK dialogs for opening or saving files.

If you wish, you can have the location entry bar always displayed instead of the breadcrumb path bar as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/101116/558158), which is still valid for Ubuntu 20.04 to at least 21.10.